# GCP credentials for Pub/Sub to Apache Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-pubsub, aws-msk-connect

I want to transfer messages from AWS MSK to GCP Pub/Sub using this [connector](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/connect_kafka).

Uploaded [connector](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/pubsub-group-kafka-connector/1.2.0/)(pubsub-group-kafka-connector-1.2.0.jar ) to the s3 bucket, created custum plugin, and want to create MKS connector with this configuration.

```
connector.class=com.google.pubsublite.kafka.sink.PubSubLiteSinkConnector 
gcp.credentials.json="service account json converted to string" 
pubsublite.project=*********
tasks.max=10
topics=my-kafka-topic 
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter 
pubsublite.topic=moove-test 
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter 
pubsublite.location=us-west1
```

I got this error[image]

I think problem with **gcp.credentials.json** argument, but succeed when convert value to json. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with succeed when convert value to json? The config itself is expecting a json, or you can use the file option and just come over the hassle here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error says that `gcp.credentials.json` cannot be parsed. Just remove the quote marks `"`.

To summarize the approach: if you have formatted JSON file, flatten the value into a single line and post it as is. Here is some example:

```
gcp.credentials.json={"type":"service_account","project_id":"","private_key_id":"","private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email":"","client_id":"","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url":""}
```

I don't think you need to escape any quote marks inside the value of JSON, unless you property file is JSON as well.